# Apache Yarn fair scheduler only allowing one application at a time

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, cloudera-cdh

We have a hadoop cluster configured with Cloudera CDH 5.4.2 distribution with Yarn fair scheduler for scheduling and managing resources. We have 18 worker nodes total amounting to 963GB main memory and 288 vcores.

Now the problem is I am able to run only one application at a time no matter how small the resource requirement of the application is. For example here is the dynamic resource pool status:

Status
YARN is using 288 vcores and 942 GiB of memory.
Resource Pools Usage

This table and the charts on the right contain metrics from YARN only.
Resource Pool Name  Allocated Memory    Allocated VCores    Allocated Containers    Pending Containers
root    0 B     0   0   0
user1   0 B     0   0   1
default     0 B     0   0   0
user2   22 GiB  11  11  1

for user 2 even though only 22GB and 11 vcores are allocated out of 288 vcores and 942 GiB of memory, there is still a pending container! any idea what is going on? This was not the case some days before, not sure what setting is causing this?

Here is my yarn-site.xml content

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <!--Autogenerated by Cloudera Manager-->
    <configuration>
      <property>
        <name>yarn.acl.enable</name>
        <value>true</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>yarn.admin.acl</name>
        <value>*</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
        <value>hadoopmaster:8032</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.admin.address</name>
        <value>hadoopmaster:8033</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
        <value>hadoopmaster:8030</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
        <value>hadoopmaster:8031</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address</name>
        <value>hadoopmaster:8088</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.https.address</name>
        <value>hadoopmaster:8090</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.client.thread-count</name>
        <value>50</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.client.thread-count</name>
        <value>50</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.admin.client.thread-count</name>
        <value>1</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
        <value>2048</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.increment-allocation-mb</name>
        <value>512</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
        <value>65536</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores</name>
        <value>1</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.increment-allocation-vcores</name>
        <value>1</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores</name>
        <value>24</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.amliveliness-monitor.interval-ms</name>
        <value>1000</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>yarn.am.liveness-monitor.expiry-interval-ms</name>
        <value>600000</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.am.max-attempts</name>
        <value>2</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.container.liveness-monitor.interval-ms</name>
        <value>600000</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.nm.liveness-monitor.interval-ms</name>
        <value>1000</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>yarn.nm.liveness-monitor.expiry-interval-ms</name>
        <value>600000</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.client.thread-count</name>
        <value>50</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>yarn.application.classpath</name>
        <value>$HADOOP_CLIENT_CONF_DIR,$HADOOP_CONF_DIR,$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/*,$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/lib/*,$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/*,$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/lib/*,$HADOOP_YARN_HOME/*,$HADOOP_YARN_HOME/lib/*</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.class</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.fair.user-as-default-queue</name>
        <value>true</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.fair.preemption</name>
        <value>true</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.fair.sizebasedweight</name>
        <value>false</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.fair.assignmultiple</name>
        <value>true</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.max-completed-applications</name>
        <value>10000</value>
      </property>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue. I have the same issue, so was wondering. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Can you please check fair-scheduler.xml file for the value "maxRunningApps" which defines number of concurrent application can run in any queue.

Please refer https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/FairScheduler.html